# Automatically set height for parent div of absolute children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a situation, where i have a few divs with absolute position (for 3d flipping effect ).
As a result, parent div's height is very small and absolute content overflows on top of lower content. Can't really set a fixed height for responsive reasons.

I'm planning to give children divs relative position, and then gather height with a help of jquery and set the height based on it. But there really is a lot of elements and vars for responsive. Is there any other, more elegant way to make children fit the parent?

http://jsfiddle.net/xyjrLa2p/

html

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="absolute">
    <p>Absolute</p>
    <p>Absolute</p>
    <p>Absolute</p>
</div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
position:relative;
background-color:yellow;
}
.absolute {
position:absolute;
}
.absolute p {
padding:5px;
}
.clearboth {
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: added code and a snippet

Comment: why do yo need this to be position:absolute? is there a real reason, or you just think you need it but not sure? I'm asking because the answer to 99 out of 100 questions at SO involving position:absolute involves "get rid of position:absolute" as part of the answer, if not the whole answer

Comment: 3d flip like that one  jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/GDdtS

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `.absolute` posistion, try to make it `relative`:

```
.absolute {
    position:relative;
}
```

Working example -- http://jsfiddle.net/xyjrLa2p/3/

Comment: I wish it was that easy ) doing a 3d flip there. That's a short and simplified piece of code. Doing something like that http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/GDdtS/ there

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I expected, this is another of those "*99 out of 100 answers*". As a rule of thumb, remember that if you're thinking of *responsive design*, chances of using *absolute* position are really slim, close to 0, because it's the absolute opposite to *responsiveness*, unless you're planning to deal with LOTS of media queries.

So, in your case and your sample, here you have:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can add some `min-width` or `max-width` in pixels or add a `media-query` to change the `vh/vw` behavior at some point, but there you go, fully responsive behavior with (obviously) no absolute position.

Always remember: if you want to use `position:absolute`, it should be inside a container with `position:relative`. While there are exceptions to this, it's an easy rule that will save you a lot of trouble at the time of positioning elements.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hchg97gd/)

Comment: so add a different class like flip.diffClass and change the height, what does it have to do with position:absolute?

Comment: the problem is (my bad, i should've made it clear from the beginning), there are a few divs on the flip with different height on collapse. What i'm doing there, is: 1)Face side is a section list of portfolio. 2) Backside is an actual portfolio section. There are a few of them and they are hidden. On click, portfolio containing div flips, and one of sections shows. As you can imagine, each section has a different number of items. So, when they collapse on smaller screen, height is really going to be different for each of the sections. (Or may be i just don't understand something)

Comment: Now that i saw your comment, i guess i'm gonna add class on click and media queries from there. not very dynamic, but should fix the problem. site is static any way.